# How use 3 AND in same selection?

Tags: php, mysql

How write this code properly..... Here i am used 3 'AND' and its showing error...Please help me...

```
 if(isset($_GET['datepicker'])){
 $mydate = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['datepicker']);
 }
 if(isset($_GET['cityText'])){
 $city1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cityText']);
 }

 if(isset($_GET['categoryValue'])){
$category1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CategoryValue']);
}

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE gcity = '$city1' AND day1 = '$mydate' AND category = '$category1'"
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: "Error with the sql query you entered: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' day1 = 'Saturday, 08 Sep, 2012', category = ''' at line 1"

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($sql)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mispelled your variable name, categoryValue is written once without a starting capital and with a capital on the second time. Variable names are case-sensitive.

Replace

```
if(isset($_GET['categoryValue'])){
$category1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['CategoryValue']);
}
```

With

```
if(isset($_GET['categoryValue'])){
    $category1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['categoryValue']);
}
```

Comment: what kind of answer it's this ?

Comment: Notice the capital C that should not be...

Comment: @MihaiIorga I thought the same thing, but it's true. While the answerer didn't answer it very well, he changed the `$_GET` variable being set from `CategoryValue` to `categoryValue`.

Comment: I see now :), must change my eyes

Comment: Thanks Salketer.....its working.....Thankyou very much....Your eyes superb!!!!

Comment: If you var_dump($city1,$category1,$mydate); you might see that one has no value, correct your variable name. The SQL error you posted after is because city1 is empty. My answer only corrects for the error you would get after this one.

Answer (score 1):

There seems no problem in the query except in declaring php variable inside it:

Try this way:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM general WHERE gcity = '".$city1."' AND day1 = '".$mydate."' AND category = '".$category1."'"`

Comment: it is also right how variables are used in the question .